# What standard of evidence is used in suits related to Texas SB8?

Tags: texas, abortion, texas-sb8

If someone sues another person over a claimed infringement of Texas' new professedly anti-abortion bill, what standard of evidence is used? The bill itself calls its enforcement provision a "civil liability". Does that mean the claim needs to be proven beyond reasonable doubt, as it would in a criminal trial, or will the court look at the preponderance of the evidence as in most other trials about a civil liability?

Comment: The phrase "anti-women" strikes me as irrelevant to the question and a potential magnet for political arguments, which are not what this site is about. To stop the endless string of off-topic comments before it starts, I suggest replacing it with "anti-abortion", which would be both more neutral and more informative about what the law does.

Comment: @MJ713 I changed it to professedly anti-abortion, maybe that's more neutral.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The standard of proof for civil cases in Texas is generally "preponderance of evidence". See [in re Steven Lipsky](https://www.txcourts.gov/media/943997/130928.pdf) for some discussion.

> The  applicable  evidentiary  standard is  generally  determined  by
> the  nature  of  the  case or particular claim.  Criminal cases
> require proof beyond a reasonable doubt, a near certainty, whereas
> civil  cases  typically  apply  the  preponderance-of-the-evidence
> standard,  that  is,  a  fact-finder’s determination  that  the
> plaintiff’s  version  of  the  events  is  more  likely  than  not
> true.   Some  civil claims, including some defamation claims, elevate
> the evidentiary standard to require proof by clear- and-convincing
> evidence.

See [Sec. 171.208](https://legiscan.com/TX/text/SB8/id/2395961) of SB8. There is no specific statutory specification of the evidentiary standard, therefore the standard is "preponderance of evidence" (compare *Lipsky*: the issue is that the statute refers to "clear and specific evidence" which is not defines in the statute or elsewhere, hence that lawsuit).